# How to make my laravel smtp credential can't be checked using checker tools

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I'm using gmail smtp server to send email in my laravel project, but few days ago I found that the email that I used in the credential sending the smtp credential (from checker result) to another email. After that my email is used to send spam emails. I try to change password for the email used, but still not working, the spam emails still sent. Is there any way I can do to prevent my smtp credential to be checked?

The credential is saved in .env, and the application already in production.

Comment: where are you storing your SMTP credentials? in .env? is your application in production?

Comment: yes, its in .env, application already in production too @KGG